# TypeError: cythonize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'module_list'

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to compile a python function into C using cython. The function *main.py* is:

```
def Factorial(y):
    x=0
    for i in range(1,y-1):
        x+=i
    return x
```

I have rewriten it in Cython code in *main.pyx*:

```
def Factorial_cdef(int y):
    return(Factorial_in_c(y))

cdef int Factorial_in_c(int y):
    int x = 0
    int i
    
    for i in range(1,y+1):
        x+=i
    return x

cpdef int Factorial_cpdef(int y):
    return Factorial_cdef(y)
```

To compile into C i have created the script *setup.py*:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
 
ext_modules = cythonize(
               compiler_directives={'language_level' : "3"} 
)
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize('main_10factorial.pyx')
)
```

Running the code in the command line (within the same folder):

```
py setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cythonize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'module_list'
```

I can not find any reference to this error online

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `cythonize` call there that's missing the module list.
Just do

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        "main_10factorial.pyx",
        compiler_directives={
            "language_level": "3"
        },
    )
)
```

and you should be good to go.